# apache domain names are case sensitive

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

The following HTTP request results in a "See the error log for more details; Invalid Value Found For Domain" error:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.MyWebsite.com
```

If I make the hostname all lowercase, however, it works just fine.

How can I make Apache case insensitive? Here's my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com

        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried adding `ServerAlias www.MyWebsite.com` to that but that didn't help. And in any event, it seems like that's a poor approach anyway since the case can be mixed up in a ton of different ways and trying to account for all of them would result in a huge *.conf file.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So what was in the error log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This set of Rewrite lines will lowercase all your requests.

```
RewriteMap    lowercase      int:tolower
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) http://${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}}$1 [R,L]
```

Hope that helps.